# CalDAV Partial Retrieval of Events by Time Range; Namespace error

Tags: webdav, jackrabbit, caldav

Currently I try to implement a CalDAV client using the Jackrabbit Libery and the information out of the [RFC 4791 CalDAV](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4791.txt)

Based on the example out of the RFC for Partial Retrieval of Events by Time Range I implemented the following code to execute a ReportMethod.

```
 public void test(String strUri, String strXMLFile) {
  try {
   Document docXMLRequest = XMLUtilities.loadXMLFile(strXMLFile);           
   ReportInfo repInfo = new ReportInfo(docXMLRequest.getDocumentElement(), DavConstants.DEPTH_INFINITY);

   ReportMethod repMethod = new ReportMethod(strUri, repInfo);
  } catch (DavException | IOException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
 }
```

The used xml content which is contained in **docXMLRequest** is the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<C:calendar-query xmlns:D="DAV:"
              xmlns:C="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:caldav">
  <D:prop>
    <D:getetag/>
    <C:calendar-data>
      <C:comp name="VCALENDAR">
        <C:prop name="VERSION"/>
        <C:comp name="VEVENT">
          <C:prop name="SUMMARY"/>
          <C:prop name="UID"/>
          <C:prop name="DTSTART"/>
          <C:prop name="DTEND"/>
          <C:prop name="DURATION"/>
          <C:prop name="RRULE"/>
          <C:prop name="RDATE"/>
          <C:prop name="EXRULE"/>
          <C:prop name="EXDATE"/>
          <C:prop name="RECURRENCE-ID"/>
        </C:comp>
        <C:comp name="VTIMEZONE"/>
      </C:comp>
    </C:calendar-data>
  </D:prop>
  <C:filter>
    <C:comp-filter name="VCALENDAR">
      <C:comp-filter name="VEVENT">
        <C:time-range start="20060104T000000Z" end="20060105T000000Z"/>
      </C:comp-filter>
    </C:comp-filter>
  </C:filter>
</C:calendar-query>
```

When I try to fire the request to the server I always get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.w3c.dom.DOMException: NAMESPACE_ERR: An attempt is made to create or change an object in a way which is incorrect with regard to namespaces.
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.ElementNSImpl.setName(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.ElementNSImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.CoreDocumentImpl.createElementNS(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.webdav.xml.DomUtil.createElement(DomUtil.java:549)
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.webdav.version.report.ReportInfo.toXml(ReportInfo.java:250)
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.webdav.client.methods.DavMethodBase.setRequestBody(DavMethodBase.java:204)
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.webdav.client.methods.ReportMethod.<init>(ReportMethod.java:44)
    at webDAVStuff.ManageWebDAV.test(ManageWebDAV.java:117)
    at mainTestRuns.MainTestSyncCalender.main(MainTestSyncCalender.java:24)
```

Following the XMLUtilities (relevant Method):

```
static public Document loadXMLFile(String strXMLFile) {
try {
    Status.printStatusToConsole("Load: "+ strXMLFile);

    File fileXMLFile = new File(strXMLFile);
    DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder dBuilder;

    dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
    dbFactory.setNamespaceAware(true);
    Document docXMLFile = dBuilder.parse(fileXMLFile);
    docXMLFile.getDocumentElement().normalize();

    return docXMLFile;
} catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (SAXException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

return null;
}
```

May someone have an idea?

Thanks and a good evening!

Answer (score 0):

From which package is the XMLUtilities thing? Does it parse the the XML document in a namespace aware method? (setNamespaceAware(true)).

Also, do not use DavConstants.DEPTH_INFINITY here. Use DEPTH_1.

Comment: Thanks for the hints. Added the loadXMLFile Method to the question and tried as well as the DEPTH_1 constant – same error.
Thanks for your help.